# Why accessing fields of struct through a typedef-ed pointer does not work?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have these declarations:

```
typedef struct egObject {
    int  magicnumber;
} egObject;
typedef struct egObject* ego;

ego e;
//printf("%d",e->magicnumber);
```

I want to get the magicnumber out of `e`, but `e->magicnumber` doesn't work. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Is `e` pointing somewhere useful? `egObject value; ego e = &value;` for example?  @AlexFarber, `e.magicnumber` is wrong since `e` is a pointer.  (I don't usually like `typedef`s that hide away the fact that it's a pointer.)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is like a "Black Box" for us. Clearly specify your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a `struct`, you allocate memory for a `struct`:

```
egObject e;
```

When you declare a pointer to a `struct`, `typedef`-ed or not, you allocate space to the *pointer*, but not for the `struct`. In order to access a field of a `struct` you need to allocate that `struct` first. A particular way in which you do it does not matter - you could allocate it statically, dynamically, or in the automated storage, but you must allocate some memory for it:

```
ego e = malloc(sizeof(*e));
```

That is enough to access the field for writing. Reading that field requires initialization, because `malloc`-ed block contains uninitialized bytes in the area allocated to `magicnumber`:

```
e->magicnumber = 123;
```

Now you can print `magicnumber` the way that your code did:

```
printf("%d",e->magicnumber);
```

Note: if you choose dynamic allocation with `malloc`, you need to `free` the object once you are done using it:

```
free(e); // Avoid memory leaks
```

Comment: Can you please help me fix the title of this question?  Something like "Why can't I dereference a structure from a pointer to that structure without allocating the memory first?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would make it a self-answering title :-)

Answer (score 3):

The line `ego e;` is essentially the same as `struct egObject *e`. The issue there is that this line only allocates memory for a **pointer to struct** it never allocates memory for the **struct**. Because you never actually make a struct, there is no reason to be able to access one of its members.

To do this correctly you could:

```
struct egObject obj; //allocate one struct
ego e = &obj;        //allocate one pointer to struct and 
                     // fill that pointer with the address of your struct

//e now 'points' to 'obj' 
//so you can use e->magicnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to print the `magicnumber` element of both an `egObject`, or `ego` (a pointer to an `egObject`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct egObject {
    int  magicnumber;
} egObject;
typedef struct egObject* ego;

int main ()
   {
   egObject eo =
      {
      .magicnumber = 42
      };

   ego e = &eo;

   printf("eo.magicnumber = %d\n",eo.magicnumber);
   printf("e->magicnumber = %d\n",e->magicnumber);

   return 0;
   }
```

Results:

```
> ./test
eo.magicnumber = 42
e->magicnumber = 42
>
```